# Android, reading preferences

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences

I am a noob learning android and building a simple game at the same time to face "real world problems" as I learn, the game is a simple maths game where two numbers are given and you have to choose the answer.

This is how I am doing it right now:
My little demo game starts (startscreen.java), click to go to the levels activity

in the levels activity (levels.java) I check the shared prefs for which level has passed (1 to 5) and display the highest, there is also a button to start the game.

Once the game is started (game.java), on 3 wrong answers I save the level to sharedpreferences if this level is higher than before and finish() the game to come back to the levels activity.

My problem is, when I come back to the levels activity now (from the game activity), it does not show the latest level that was just saved in the game activity :(
but if I restart the game or go to startscreen.java and come back it shows.

I can paste the code here if you need me to but I suspect you guys have already solved this :)
Thanks!
Ryan

EDIT:
Added onResume, but it still does not work, my code:
http://www.pastebin.com/wUUcpMDi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the onResume method of your levels activity to tell the UI to refresh with the new level information.

Comment: Thanks guys! Since you answered first will pick yours and vote the rest up :)

Comment: Where are you setting the preference?  Show us that code.  Also, get the debugger working ;)

Comment: Yes, I found that after posting and deleted it :)) I put the toast in onResume and see that that is firing... but it does not update the UI :(

Comment: Nevermind, got it working now via another method, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

OnCreate() is only called when your activity is created. Try putting the code that reads the sharedpreferences in the OnResume(). See android activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that all info will be restored when you get back to your preference screen, you should store these values inside `SharedPreference`. Based on your question I assume you're familiar with using it. Just put your latest level value inside `SharedPreference`, then fetch it when you get back to the level activity and check the corresponding row. Hope this helps.